# Scraping a specific <p> class from Yahoo Finance (VBA, Excel)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract specific information from a certain nested class

from the code at the following location
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASUR?p=ASUR

The class where in innertext is located is named "D(ib) Va(t)" and as far as I have seen at least this text is unique for the class name. I am using the following code to get the data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim IE4 As Object
Dim strURL3 As String
Dim divs1 As Object
Dim symbol1 As String
Dim rowd As Integer
Dim divs2 As Object

'turn calculation off

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

rowd = 1
'Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
'Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "Industry"

'Worksheets("Panel").Activate
'Range("B9").Select
Set IE4 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create only one IE instance


'Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" 'Loop
'symbol1 = ActiveCell.Value

strURL3 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASUR?p=ASUR"

IE4.Visible = True 'Flag to remove IE visibility
        VBA.Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 264", vbMinimizedNoFocus
        VBA.Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 258", vbMinimizedNoFocus
        IE4.Navigate strURL3
        While IE4.Busy: DoEvents: Wend 'Break of 4 seconds after loading
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))


Set divs1 = IE4.Document.getelementsbytagname("div")

  Worksheets("Industry").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Cells("1,2").Select
 For Each div In divs1
          Set divs2 = IE4.Document.getelementsbytagname("p")
           For Each p In divs2

           If p.classname = "D(ib) Va(t)" Then

            Debug.Print p.innertext

            'Cells(rowd, 2) = p.innertext
            'rowd = rowd + 1
            End If
          Next p

Next div

 'Sheets("Panel").Select
' ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 'Loop
    'Sheets("Panel").Select
    'Range("B9").Select 'range that selects rows and columns to paste in every company sheet
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   ' Selection.Copy
   ' Sheets("Industry").Select
    'Range("A1").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
   ' Application.CutCopyMode = False

 IE4.Quit

'turn calculation on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It does not capture the

class, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The `p` tag element with that class includes the company sector, industry and employee info. You can use a faster method of xmlhttp to retrieve by avoiding opening a browser. Then use a css selector combination to target the element

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASUR?p=ASUR"
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responsetext
    End With
    Debug.Print html.querySelector("p.D\(ib\).Va\(t\)").innerText
End Sub
```

If you want to avoid compound classes you can use the following:

```
Debug.Print html.querySelector("p + .D\(ib\)").innerText
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to go for selecting compound classes as long as there is a way to avoid that. Check out the following implementation to achieve the same result:

```
Sub FetchText()
    Const Link$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASUR?p=ASUR"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Link, False
        .send
        Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    MsgBox Htmldoc.querySelector("p.businessSummary").PreviousSibling.LastChild.innerText
End Sub
```

Comment: why is using compound classes worse than chaining? The path with compound is actually shorter and faster.

Comment: Any minimum changes of that website's structure will possibly lead to a fiasco If you use compound classes @QHarr. For example, if this classes "D(ib) Va(t)" are not in order or they have got an extra space between them or no space at all then your suggested css selector will fail miserably. No script is meant to use for a single time. Durability matters. Thanks.

Comment: A fiasco? Sounds rather fun.  No space at all wouldn't matter in this case would it?  I agree on the point of the extra space and the ordering is not something I had thought of so + for that. I hadn't seen any warnings about compound classes, in fact they are on the up due to the flexibility that allow for specificity rules.

Comment: That is the reason I used ***or***. My comment is not meant is this very case only; rather, all the compound classes used in different cases. Thanks.